# To parse Json string containing array of Objects and Getting specificvalue from Json String

Tags: java, android, json, string, parsing

*Here is my Json String. I want To extract Country Name  and Country Id of each Object..
please Help Me for the Same*

String===

[{"CountryID":1,"CountryIDNew":1,"Name":"India","Shname":"IN","Des":null,"InternationalCode":null,"ISDCode":"091","Active":true,"SoftDelete":false,"CountryDef":null,"DateOfEntry":"/Date(1380515350000)/","LatestModified":false,"FYID":44,"PeriodId":6,"UserId":107},{"CountryID":2,"CountryIDNew":1,"Name":"India","Shname":"IN","Des":null,"InternationalCode":null,"ISDCode":"091","Active":true,"SoftDelete":false,"CountryDef":null,"DateOfEntry":"/Date(1387793898000)/","LatestModified":true,"FYID":44,"PeriodId":9,"UserId":117}]

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android for answers about how to parse JSON in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this android code.

```
 JsonArray resultJson = new JSONArray(json_string);

    for(int i=0;i<resultJson.length();i++)
    {

    JsonObject jobj = (JSONObject) resultJson.get(i);
    String country_id = jobj.getString("CountryID");
    String country_name = jobj.getString("Name");

    }
```

Comment: "[{"CountryID":1,"CountryIDNew":1,"Name":"India","Shname":"IN","Des":null,"InternationalCode":null,"ISDCode":"091","Active":true,"SoftDelete":false,"CountryDef":null,"DateOfEntry":"/Date(1380515350000)/","LatestModified":false,"FYID":44,"PeriodId":6,"UserId":107},{"CountryID":2,"CountryIDNew":1,"Name":"India","Shname":"IN","Des":null,"InternationalCode":null,"ISDCode":"091","Active":true,"SoftDelete":false,"CountryDef":null,"DateOfEntry":"/Date(1387793898000)/","LatestModified":true,"FYID":44,"PeriodId":9,"UserId":117}]";
This type of String Is not Accepted in Java code For Processing

Comment: (")should be replace by(\") for processing but how to generate that string from JSON object???

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

Create a class

```
   public class Country{ public String name =""; public String countryId =""; }
```

And create a array list

ArrayList countryList = new ArrayList();

```
String serverRes = "[{"CountryID":1,"CountryIDNew":1,"Name":"India","Shname":"IN","Des":null,"InternationalCode":null,"ISDCode":"091","Active":true,"SoftDelete":false,"CountryDef":null,"DateOfEntry":"/Date(1380515350000)/","LatestModified":false,"FYID":44,"PeriodId":6,"UserId":107},{"CountryID":2,"CountryIDNew":1,"Name":"India","Shname":"IN","Des":null,"InternationalCode":null,"ISDCode":"091","Active":true,"SoftDelete":false,"CountryDef":null,"DateOfEntry":"/Date(1387793898000)/","LatestModified":true,"FYID":44,"PeriodId":9,"UserId":117}]";


JSONArray response = new JSONArray(serverRes);

    for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
    {

    JSONObject jobj =  response.getJSONObject(i);
        Country c = new  Country();
    c.name = jobj.getString("CountryID");
    c.countryId = jobj.getString("Name");
         countryList.add(c);
    }
```

And you can get array list with data.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
JsonArray resultJson = new JSONArray(json_string);

for(int i=0;i<resultJson.length();i++)
{
     JsonObject jobj = resultJson.getJSONObject(i);
     if( jobj.has("CountryID") )
     {
           String country_id = jobj.getString("CountryID");
     }
     if( jobj.has("Name") )
      {
           String country_name = jobj.getString("Name");
     }
}
```

hope this help you